# Convert names and languages to a list of pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello Friends can someone help me with it?

[image: This is the code]

and i have a text document of names like this

[image: names (languages)]

New Problem:

[image: Code]

[it still doesnt work..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJhgV.png)

Comment: Your code is fine, apart from the fact that `dict.iteritems` doesn't exist in Python 3. You should use `items` instead

Comment: ok thanks, i have although a problem to run it, can you check the new description please

Comment: Try both and see which one works. Also try `DataDict.items` and make sure you understand how it's different from `dict.items`.

Comment: Wait, what's `DataDict`? I thought it was a variable, oops. You should be using `data.items` then

Comment: Don’t post pictures of code. Post and format the actual code as text.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a point creating an extra variable and the whole function for something that could be a simple oneliner:

```
data_list = [ (k,v) for k,v in data.items() ]
```

You can make it a `list` as well, but I think `tuple` fits better in this case.

Comment: my teacher wants me to do it like that 

TODO: it's your job to implement this function.
def convert(data: DataDict) -> DataList:
    """
    Convert the dictionary representation to the listc
    of (name, language) pairs.
    """

Comment: @NewCodeer well. you may put this oneliner inside your function =)

Comment: i did i got the same problem like i mentioned in my post "new Problem:"

Comment: @NewCodeer please, use `data` instead of `DataDict`

Comment: @NewCodeer seems like `DataList` and `DataDict` are some classes names or something. weird.